# A way to group table cells together in html?

Tags: html, html-table, grouping, cells

So it is pretty straight forward. I need a way to group cells together. Like a `<div>` or a `<span>` but none of them worked. `<tbody>` seemed like a good solution but it only works for table rows. Help!

Comment: are you trying to wrap `<TD>` tags inside `<DIV>`'s? is that the basic idea?

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a way to **merge** 2 o more cells in a row into one single cell, along with other "*regular*" cells (as you would do in a google|excel spreadsheet) in a way similar to this:

[image: Merged Cells inside a table with other regular rows]

then you can use the `colspan` attribute for `td` elements, indicating how many cells are you *merging*:

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan=2> Merged Cell occupying 2 columns </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> Regular cell </td>
  <td> Another cell in same row </td>
</tr>
```

Additionally, you can use the `td[colspan]` selector in css (combined with any parent selector of your choice) to refer to these merged cells.

Here's a working example:

```css
/* Style for cells with any colspan attribute */
td[colspan] {
  text-align: center;
}

/* No extra space between cells */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Invoice</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- this cell will occupy 3 columns -->
    <td colspan=3>January</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0348</td>
    <td>248.35</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>0349</td>
    <td>126.14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>0350</td>
    <td>821.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>February</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>0351</td>
    <td>643.50</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the html `col` tag to group the columns `td`.

```css
.col-group-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
 }

.col-group-2 {
  background-color: silver;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="col-group-1">
    <col span="2" class="col-group-2">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>New york</td>
    <td>987654321</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magdalena</td>
    <td>Los Angeles</td>
    <td>123456789</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Please check out the [html col tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp)

and how to use them with  [css styling](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/columns.html)

Comment: Not flexible enough. Take my case as an example. I need a wrapper tag every 3 cells. It is ideal if there's some tag under `tr` and above `td`

Comment: Can't just copy paste from W3Schools dude... -1